# Application configuration files for Windows Universal app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have developed a Windows 8.1 Universal app for tablets and phones.

Is there any equivalent of App.config file what we used to have in desktop applications in win 8.1 tablets and phones ?

Searching over the net revealed nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No direct equivalent, you need to create something similar by yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings in Windows.Storage namespace. 
Please refer to: [Loading and saving settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263230.aspx)