# Windows 10 Universal App - Best way to store static application settings

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I would like to store some configurable data (hosts, keys etc.) in my universal app. The data would be defined before running the app and never changed at runtime. What is the best way to achieve this? I've come across a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730825/application-configuration-files-for-windows-universal-app), but there must be some built-in mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

- Here you will find some info: [Store and retrieve settings and other app data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt299098.aspx)
- If you want to have a file with settings that are known at compile time you can add a json or xml file in your solution and use it as a config file in code.